# Create UI with netbeans for different size!

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I want to create UI for my program with netbeans but I don't know how to create a UI that when user change the size of program window( maximize or other sizes ) component of the program change sizes for match to that program size.

I want to create a GUI for aria2c download manager like Google Chrome that has one button to change state from HTTP to FTP or metalink and so on and a textField for import users download link and a button for settings like Google Chrome.  Below this toolbar I want to show things that user want to download like IDM.  That IDM show name and status of things that user want to download.  Please suggest how I can create this GUI and which layout manager is comfortable for creating this GUI. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either GridLayout or BorderLayout. Also read this: [Using Layout Manager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Answer (score 1):

Agree 100% with Harry.  Also:

- Avoid using NetBeans default GroupLayout
- Learn about nesting JPanels each with its own simple layout to in effect nest layout managers and create complex layouts.
- Probably avoid usingGridBagLayout early on when learning to use layout managers and use the more simple ones if possible. Consider using [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) if you need a complex gridbag-like layout and nesting of simple layouts doesn't solve the problem.
- If stuck, post an image of your desired GUI layout and your latest code attempt, and we'll be able to give you more specific advice.

Comment: I basically aggree except for "avoid GridBagLayout". The NetBeans GUI designer makes it quite easy to understand the dreaded GBL, and once you get the hang of it, it's very powerful

Comment: @ahorse: I agree. That's why I said "avoid GridBagLayout early on". The tutorial make it sound as if it is the first layout that should be used in most situations when I think it is more important to learn the simpler more basic ones first, and then move on to GridBagLayout.

Comment: Thanks for yours helps.i want to create UI for aria2c download manager for linux and i want create gui like google chrome that has textField to enter download link and one button to change state from http to metalink and so on. and i want to create a panel like mac os dock or ubuntu unity can i do this with toolBox? i am student in java world please help me to learn more things! i want to create simple to use GUI for this application and for efficient.